# Why isn't my mysql query from python shell going through to the web hosting database

Tags: php, python, mysql

ok so I have the following code that I am running in the python shell:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "xxxx",user="xxxx"password="xxxx",db="xxxx")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(CREATE TABLE qqqq (asdf VARCHAR(20),fdsa VARCHAR(20))
```

Fairly sure the connection part is working, I'll get an error if I enter in the wrong value, or if I deny access to the database for my computer's IP address.

on the webhosting server, I have the following basic index.php file, which I have tested on a server on my computer, and I know works. when I go to the website domain, I get the following error: "Database query failed."

Any ideas why the MySQL query isn't working? My webhosting is Cpanel with godaddy.com, should I look for something else?

```
<?php
$dbhost = "xxxx";
$dbuser = "xxxx";
$dbpass = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); /*1*/

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() .
        " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    }

?> 
<?php
 $query ="SELECT * FROM qqqq"; /*2*/
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 if (!$result) {
die("Database query failed.");
 } 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<?php /*3*/
while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?><li><?php echo $subject['asdf'];?></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
    mysqli_free_result($result); /*4*/
?>

</body>
</html>

<?php 
mysqli_close($connection); /*5*/
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: nothing in particular. Is there a way to get the response from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call db.commit() to have it complete. By default, autocommit is turned off.

You also have an error in your code. The SQL should be a string.

Comment: yes that works, nvm, I was being stupid and pasting in multiple lines at the same time.

Comment: Awesome! Could you please accept this as the answer?

Comment: as soon as i figure out how

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the cursor execute be calling a string?  You don't have quotes around your sql statement.

Comment: thanks, I must have just copied it wrong, I use quotes in the actual python shell.

Answer (score 0):

This line without quotas is incorrect:

```
cur.execute(CREATE TABLE qqqq (asdf VARCHAR(20),fdsa VARCHAR(20))
```

It should be

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE qqqq (asdf VARCHAR(20),fdsa VARCHAR(20))")
```

So test in your database whether you really have table `qqqq`.
You could install [SQL Buddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/) or phpMyAdmin.